# How to check if two url point to same controller and action, in cakephp 3?

Tags: url, cakephp-3.0

I have an url like this.`$myUrl = 'posts/index';`. And I need to compare this url with another url that passed to my method to find if both of them have equal controller and action.

```
public function compareUrls($url) {
    $myUrl = 'posts/index';
    //returns true if both urls point to the same controller and action otherwise returns false
}
```

The passed url can be any legal url in cakephp. For example:

```
$url0 = '/';//false
$url1 = 'posts';//true
$url2 = 'posts/index';//true
$url3 = 'en/posts/index/3/foo';//true
$url4 = ['controller'=>'posts' , 'action'=>'index'];//true
$url5 = ['controller'=>'posts' , 'action'=>'index' , 'p1' , 'p2'];//true
```

Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your function might be

```
public function compareUrls($urlString)
{
    $myUrlString = 'posts/index';
    $myUrl = Router::parse($myUrlString);
    $url = Router::parse($urlString);
    if ($myUrl['controller'] == $url['controller'] && $myUrl['action'] == $url['action']) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Route::parse](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.Route.Route.html#_parse) could do it.

Example: `debug(Router::parse('/admin/users/index'))` will return

```
[
    'controller' => 'Admin',
    'action' => 'users',
    'pass' => [
        (int) 0 => 'index'
    ],
    'plugin' => null
]
```

> Note that
>   [Route::parse](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.Route.Route.html#_parse)
>   only for string url and you need to use `Cake\Routing\Router` namspace in your controller